# Arrow using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create an arrow like the one I have attached, using just css.

[image]

I found the following [article](http://jsfiddle.net/veuc78af/), but I couldn't remove only one pointy end.

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  color: #fd0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:before {
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}

.button:after {
  top: 40px;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}


/* Button Border Style */

.button.border:before,
.button.border:after {
  border: 4px solid #fd0;
}

.button.border:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}

.button.border:after {
  border-top: none;
  /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}


/* Button hover styles */

.button.border:hover:before,
.button.border:hover:after {
  background: #fd0;
}

.button.border:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>

<br/>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? such as removing the :before rules or else ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Only removing the `:before` won't work in this case

Comment: @AbhishekPandey i know, but did the OP tried anything beside. posting:' I want ... '

Comment: @GCyrillus I agree! He should have mentioned.

Comment: @GCyrillus I did try to solve this before posting. But none of them really worked for me. Probably because I'm not familiar with ":before and :after" keywords. Thanks

Comment: oki,  telling what you tried, avoid helper to go through the same path before to find out that it doesn't work and then focus on the reason or on another method ;)

Comment: Duly noted. I posted the article I referred. rather than posting the odd shapes I generated. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `transform-origin: left;`to make it only on one side in `:before`and `:after`

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  color: #fd0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:before {
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
   transform-origin: left;
}

.button:after {
  top: 40px;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
   transform-origin: left;
}


/* Button Border Style */

.button.border:before,
.button.border:after {
  border: 4px solid #fd0;
}

.button.border:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}

.button.border:after {
  border-top: none;
  /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}


/* Button hover styles */

.button.border:hover:before,
.button.border:hover:after {
  background: #fd0;
}

.button.border:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>

<br/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see here - you need to put together the works of different border widths in the before and after elements:

```
<div id="myarrow">My new arrow!</div>


 #myarrow {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   position: relative;
 }

 #myarrow:after {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border: 25px solid transparent;
   border-left: 8px solid red;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 200px;
 }

 #myarrow:before {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border: 25px solid transparent;
   border-left: 8px solid blue;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 201px;
 }
```

And here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/edL4ngt4/

Answer (score 3):

Link to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZVRpE)

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -9px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -9px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed alot, I removed the `:before` and created a new `:after` which is rotated by `45deg`. This have a border. Thats all.

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  color: #fd0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-top: 3px solid yellow;
  border-left: 3px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}

.button::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: -28px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
  border-right: 3px solid yellow;
  top: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* Button hover styles */

.button.border:hover:after {
  background-color: #fd0;
}

.button.border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fd0;
}


/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>

<br/>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">I have a huge amount of text inside !!!!!!!!!!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following class in css by the code below.

```
<style>
    .button:after {
        position: absolute;
        content:'';
        width: 100%;
        left: -5px;
        height: 34px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
     .button {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        color: #fd0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 80px;
        border-left:4px solid red;
    }
    </style>
```